# Route для кириллицы в Express

Tags: регулярные-выражения, node.js, express

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы маршрутизатор пропускал выражения, с буквами и символами, типа `a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я_`. Как я это делаю:

```
rootApp.all(/\+(\w+|\p{L}+)/, function (req, res, next) {
    res.cookie("referer", req.params[0]);
    res.send(req.params);
});
```

Но в итоге...

`GET /+А - 404 NOT FOUND
GET /+ref - {"0":"ref"}
GET /+ref_123ру_ - {"0":"ref_123"}`

Как сделать, чтобы парсер пропускал кириллицу?

**UPDATE**: Оказывается, что ссылка кодируется URL символами. Даже если декодировать ее, все равно парсинг не работает.

```
    rootApp.all(/\+(\S)/, function (req, res, next) {
    var decodedPath = decodeURIComponent(req.path),
        regexp = /\+(\w+|\p{IsCyrillic}+|\p{L}+)/;

    console.log(decodedPath);
    if (regexp.test(decodedPath)) {
        var parsed = regexp.exec(decodedPath);

        console.log("Parsed String: ", parsed);
        res.cookie("referer", parsed[1]);
        res.send(parsed);
    }
    else next();
});
```

Консоль

```
/+ref_123ру_
Parsed String:  [ '+ref_123', 'ref_123', index: 1, input: '/+ref_123ру_' ]
```

Comment: Так допишите кирилицу. Но мне кажется, что скорее всего нужно добавить % т.к. строки url кодируют её через %

Comment: Так есть кириллица. В первом запросе это русская "А", в третьем "ру".

Comment: Разные программы с кирилицей работают по-разному.  кирилица кодируется regex-ом [А-Яа-я], но именно для URL адреса могут иметь вид  http://%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81.%D1%80%D1%83 (яндекс.ру - простое кодирование), плюс ещё могут быть unicode % c 4-значным хекс. Попробуйте добавить %.

Comment: @nick_n_a я обновил ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: `\p{IsCyrillic}` не поддерживается RegExp. Как и все остальные классы Юникода, начинающиеся с `\p`.

Comment: Может таки добавить процент? regexp = /\+(\w+|%+|\p{IsCyrillic}+|\p{L}+)/;   или переписать так /\+[0-9A-Za-z%&]+/

Comment: @nick_n_a не работает. Добавление процента никак не поможет, ведь мне нужно спасить строку.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew а как тогда сделать?

Comment: Для того чтобы найти строку символов кириллицы, используйте `[а-яА-ЯЁё]+`. К сожалению, я не специалист по  express. Чтобы найти и латинницу и кириллицу, используйте `[а-яА-ЯЁёa-zA-Z]+`. Символы вроде `ń` нужно отлавливать с помощью библиотеки `XRegExp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге сделал так:

```js
rootApp.all(/\+(\S+)/, function (req, res, next) {
    var decodedPath = decodeURIComponent(req.path),
        regexp = /\+[a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я_]+/;

    var executed = regexp.exec(decodedPath);
    if (executed != null) {
        var parsed = executed[0].slice(1);

        res.cookie("referer", parsed);
        res.send(parsed);
    }
    else next();
});
```

Всем спасибо!

Comment: decodeURIComponent - делает из %D1 русские символы. По идее `/\+[a-zA-Z0-9%]+/ ` должно тоже работать.